# Disable field in Django on condition

Tags: django

Hi I want to disable few field in my form depending on whether a certain field has any data entered or not. If yes then I should hide them.

```
class Dictionary(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True,   
                            null=True, db_index=True)                     
    phase = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, 
                            default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    warning = models.NullBooleanField(default='Unknown', 
                            null=True, blank=True)
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(db_index=True, default=0,
                            blank=True, null=True)
    date_loaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False, 
                            null=False, help_text=u'current date ')
```

If I have name entered in the field, I should disable the fields phase and warning.

In adminx.py

```
class DictionaryAdmin(object):
reversion_enable = True
list_display = ('name','phase','warning','year','date_loaded')

list_display_links = ('name')
readonly_fields = ()
```

Adding the readonly fields would disable them always. 
Could I do this with overriding the `get_readonly_fields` given the conditions in adminx file?

```
my js file . 

    (function($) {
    $(function() {
        var name = $('name'),
            phase = $('phase'),

            warning = $('warning');

        function toggledisabed(value) {
            var checkname = /^CH[1-9][0-9+]?$/i;
            value = checkname.test(name) ?  phase.show(): phase.hide()
        }
        toggledisabled(name.val());
   });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to hide field of form, based on model via condition. So you can just use `{% if %}` tag. Like this

```
{% if model.name %}
    {{ form.field_for_name }}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

In case, if model has data in field "name", it will show, else it will hide